# How to grep file names which containg range of value(-6 to -7) in column 2 in it sub files?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

i have 5000 directories(ligand_0001 to ligand_5000 ). Each contains sub file name as log.txt which contains scores in column 2. I want to extract all those directory names (ligand_*) which have a log file that contains -6 to -7 scores in second column.

```
   1         -6.1      0.000      0.000
   2         -6.1      2.657      3.713
   3         -5.9     26.479     28.383
   4         -5.9     27.924     30.549
   5         -5.8      4.579      8.657
   6         -5.8     26.841     28.725
   7         -5.8     25.192     27.089
   8         -5.6      3.119      4.640
```

This is the sub file (log.txt) in ligand_0005 folder. i want only the name of the folder because it contain -6 to -7 value in column 2 (i.e ligand_0005)

Comment: Have you tried implementing it? If yes could you paste the code that you did and what's failing while you tried implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small `awk` script that scan all the files together in one sweep.

`script.awk`

```
BEGINFILE{ # on every file
    pathPartsLen = split(FILENAME,pathParts, "/"); # split path to its parts into arry pathParts
    currentDir = pathParts[pathPartsLen - 1]; # find the current parent dir
}
$2 ~ "^-[67]" { # match 2nd field to start with -6 or -7
    print currentDir;
    nextfile; # skip the rest of the file, goto next file
}
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk $(find ligand_* -name log.txt)
```

explaining:

`find ligand_* -name log.txt`  :  list all `log.txt` files in directories ligand_*

Comment: it's simple and straight!

Comment: i want lilttle bit changing in the script. now i want to extract only the folder names which contains -6.5 to -7 scores. how i can place the decimal in the script.

Comment: Try modify the 2nd field matching RegExp. `"^-[67]"` to `"^-(6\.5)|(7)"` test this using ` awk -f script.awk log.txt`

Comment: You can also abandon the RegExp and test for value range: `$2 > -8 && $2 <= -6.5`

Comment: I'd suggest `-6.5 <= $2 && $2 <= -7`, in case the values smaller than `-7.0` are not wanted. I also like that form as it's clear what the range is.

Comment: @DudiBoy it gives following errorawk: script.awk:5: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'

Comment: This is correct. we want to identify `.` as char and not RegEx `.`  You can do `\\.` and it will remove the warning

Comment: @DudiBoy it not show any  file name despite of having files that have 6.5 score. now i m only given 6.5 scores to sort. edit below line in the script                                        
$2 ~ "^-(6\\.5)"  { # match 2nd field to start with -6 or -7

Comment: try matching `"(^-6\\.5)|(^-7)"` the `|` is an or operator `()` are same context match.

Answer (score 0):

use awk to figure out if numbers exists in the second column, iterate over folders and check each folder's log.txt

```sh
ARRAY=()
for i in ligand_*
do
  if [[ ! -z $(awk '$2>=-7 && $2<=-6' ${i}/log.txt) ]]
  then
   ARRAY+=("${i}")
  fi
done
printf '%s\n' "${ARRAY[@]}"
```

Comment: I would put `"` around the `awk` call, and only test the second column `awk '$2 ~ /[67]\.[0-9]*/'`

Comment: That is better than what I did! Updated the answer!

Comment: I forgot in my comment the minus sign `/-[67]`

Comment: You could improve this by exiting the awk whenever you encounter a matching value, and then only test the exit status. You then `exit 1` when you match, and in the `for` loop, you'd do `awk ... || ARRAY+=${i}`

Comment: You match (-8, -6>. For example -7.9 passes your test.
I think you can use  `awk '$2>=-7 && $2<=-6'`

Comment: @JUSHJUSH you are right, the regex then must be `/-6\.[0-9]*/`, I think it's faster, but not sure

Comment: @SidraRafi Did you run it in the same folder as where the ligand_000X folders are present?

Comment: @JUSHJUSH yeah now it run but the result look like this and difficult to interpret ligand_00487ligand_00488ligand_00490ligand_00491ligand_00492ligand_00493ligand_00495ligand_00496ligand_00497ligand_00498ligand_00499ligand_00500ligand_00502ligand_00503ligand_00504ligand_00505ligand_00506ligand_00507ligand_00508ligand_00509ligand_00510ligand_00511ligand_00512ligand_00513ligand_00514ligand_00515ligand_00517ligand_00518ligand_00519ligand_00520ligand_00521ligand_00525ligand_00526ligand_00528ligand_00529ligand_00530ligand_00531ligand_00532ligand_00533ligand

Comment: Change last line(echo) to
`printf '%s\n' "${ARRAY[@]}"`

Comment: @Zelnes, you're right. Your regex is almost 2x faster.

Comment: @JUSHJUSH it gives following erorr.                                                      ./compound-name.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `to'
./compound-name.sh: line 9: `(echo) to printf '%s\n' "${ARRAY[@]}"'

Comment: @SidraRafi use only: `printf '%s\n' "${ARRAY[@]}"`

Comment: @JUSHJUSH the result is still look like before.

Comment: @SidraRafi, also change `ARRAY+=${i}` to `ARRAY+=("${i}")`.
I edited the answer, so just try it again.